# combining inline scripts in <head>

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following code in the  part of my html and was wondering how i could clean it up to optimize the loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "js/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 }

 function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 }

 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

</script>
```

Comment: Note that only *one* of those `downloadJSAtOnload` functions will get used (the second one). Also note that with current browsers, if you were to give those functions different names and call both of them, there would be no guarantee whatsoever that jQuery would be loaded before the Orbit plug-in (which would probably make the Orbit plug-in fail). You'd have a race condition.

Comment: If your goal is to allow the page to be displayed before the scripts are loaded, there's a *much* easier way: Just put the script tags (in the appropriate order) at the very end of the `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: oh ok, that is what i'm going for. then what would be a case for using and "on load event" as opposed to putting it in the body tag?

Comment: @ William: Looks like your question is really about how to load those scripts, so I've turned the comment above into an answer and addressed your follow-up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to allow the page to be displayed before the scripts are loaded, there's a *much* easier way: Just put the script tags (in the appropriate order) at the very end of the `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<!-- ...content of page... -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `load` event on the `window` object happens **very** late in the page load process, after all other resources have been completely loaded (or failed to load). So all images, both foreground and background, etc.

By putting the scripts right at the end of the body, you get them in the browser's download queue at a reasonable time, but without making the browser wait for the script to arrive before doing the initial page rendering. You also get the ordering (you'd get that with the `defer` attribute on the `script` element as well, but not all browsers support it). More: [*YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website*](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

You've asked in the comments when you would use the `load` event for script loading. My answer is: I've never had a reason for doing so.

Comment: that solves my problem of getting the content to load first but now the slideshow that i have on my website is not loading at all? www.unifiedforuganda.com